# How to find the issue with dual in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL developer. I am using the following query to get the current time stamp.

```
select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DDMMYYYY/HHMMSS') from dual;
```

In this, minutes is constantly set to 10. But when we don't use to_char, it is working fine. How to find what went wrong? Is there any method to correct this?

Comment: Probably a formatting problem in SQL Developer

Comment: Could you please help me on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Yes mi was the mistake. Could you please tell me that how the date is updated in the dual table?

Comment: The `dual` table has no role here, your problem is with your date/time format string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **`MI`** in `HHMMSS` instead of `MM`. **`MI`** stands for minutes, `MM` is for months, and currently it is October, hence the 10.

You can find the available formatting options at [Oracle's site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DDMMYYYY/HHMMSS') from dual;
```

The issue is with the `HHMMSS` - `MM` is used to represent the month number. `MI` is what is used to represent minutes.

So what you're really after is:

```
select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DDMMYYYY/HHMISS') from dual;
```